# How to divide two dataframes elementwise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, they share the same columns and one has more indexes than the other, what I want is to divide each element of one dataframe by the corresponding element (having the same index and column) in another dataframe, an example:

df1

```
    value1              value2                  
0     1                   3            
1     2                   4  
2     5                   6
```

df2

```
    value1              value2                  
0     2                   2            
1     2                   2
```

The result would be:

```
    value1              value2                  
0     0.5                 1.5            
1     1                   2
```

Also in my real example, the indexes are not ordered as here (they are dates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no missing values in original DataFrame remove only `NaN`s rows after division:

```
df = df1.div(df2).dropna(how='all')
print (df)
   value1  value2
0     0.5     1.5
1     1.0     2.0
```

Or first filter common indices in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
common = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)
df = df1.loc[common].div(df2.loc[common])
print (df)
   value1  value2
0     0.5     1.5
1     1.0     2.0
```

If need also filter common columns names:

```
common_idx = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)
common_cols = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)

df = df1.loc[common_idx, common_cols].div(df2.loc[common_idx, common_cols])
```